# Process Start in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

Want to execute a exe within Application directory, in Dev system it works fine. In IIS, it is not executed, I have tried below points:

*set default application pool to local system*

*set defualtpool, NETWORK_SERVICE, Everyone access to exe*

*Enabled 32 bit application to application pool*

Server Version : Windows Server 2012

IIS Version: IIS 8.0

**Below is my code**

```
 p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

p.StartInfo.FileName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";      

string arg1 = "";

arg1 = "www.google.com" + " test.pdf";

p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg1;

p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.Start();          

p.WaitForExit(60000);

p.Close();

p.Dispose();
```

Comment: process.start does not shows an interactive window, is that what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Do you have any error or logs?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the location at which your pdf file is getting generated "everyone has access to it"

it seems you are trying to convert html data to pdf file on your iis server. Make sure IIS server can access the site which your are trying to convert "Check if you can access those site using IE on your IIS server as there could be proxy issues"

Comment: Everyone access is given to the specified folder

Comment: Directly checked in server, same problem only

Answer (score 0):

Consider to set the working path of your exe:

```
 p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "wkhtmltopdf";
```

Also check task manager if the exe is in memory.
Sometimes when a batch got a low level error open a prompt, and IIS do not capture it, so the process is freezed in memory.

Consider also the set a log in the exe in order to understand what goes wrong.

I had similar problem. Solved moving the exe in another folder outside IIS application. This folder should have execution rights.

Comment: Tried moving exe outside IIS application, still not working. 

Even 
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
is not working in IIS

Comment: Does your exe has an user interface? or is it just a batch? Notepad has an interface where user interacts. You cannot run in iis.
In IIS you can launch exe that does something than stops. A batch without any gui.
I suggest you to create a simple exe like an "hello world" that -for example- writes in a file then stops. So you can understand the issue.
But this exe should not have a gui.